# Failed to build maven project with following maven error org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:1.12:check-file-header

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, kylo

I am trying to build Kylo v_0.9.1 using eclipse with m2e on Windows platform . But the project build fails at kylo-operational-metadata-jpa and throws following error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building kylo-operational-metadata-jpa 0.9.1.2-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ kylo-operational-metadata-jpa ---

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:1.12:update-file-header (first) @ kylo-operational-metadata-jpa ---
[WARNING] The failOnMissingHeader has no effect if the property dryRun is not set.
[WARNING] The failOnNotUptodateHeader has no effect if the property dryRun is not set.

[INFO] adding extra resolver file:/C:/Users/kylo_0_9_1/kylo/core/operational-metadata/operational-metadata-jpa/../../../license-config

[WARNING] The extension sql is already accepted for comment style sql

[INFO] Will search files to update from root C:\Users\kylo_0_9_1\kylo\core\operational-metadata\operational-metadata-jpa\target\generated-sources

[INFO] Scan 52 files header done in 1.089s.

[INFO] 
 * add header on 52 files.

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:1.12:check-file-header (first) @ kylo-operational-metadata-jpa ---

[INFO] adding extra resolver file:/C:/Users//kylo_0_9_1/kylo/core/operational-metadata/operational-metadata-jpa/../../../license-config

[WARNING] The extension sql is already accepted for comment style sql

[INFO] Will search files to update from root 



[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:1.12:check-file-header (first) on project kylo-operational-metadata-jpa:

[ERROR] There are 52 file(s) with header to update:    `
```

Answer (score 3):

The [License Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) is detecting some files that do not have a header, and hence throwing the error. You can fix this by running the below command:

```
$ mvn license:update-file-header
```

This should add the header to the missing files. Then you can attempt the build again.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven output indicates you're trying to build Kylo 0.9.2-SNAPSHOT which is an unstable version and not supported by the Kylo team.

To build Kylo 0.9.1 please try these commands:

```
git checkout v0.9.1.1
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```